Can Datagrip show Redis strings split into folders (by ":") like "Another Redis Desktop Manager" does?
In "Another Redis Desktop Manager" they show our redis strings in a really manageable way.
We have strings that look like
[Type]:[ClientCode]:[ModelType]:[Id]
In ARDM it recognises the split, and puts them into folders like so:

Which makes it much easier to navigate the strings (because they can be expanded and collapsed)
But in Datagrip it just shows all the strings in one list like so

Which makes it much harder to use.
As much as im happy with ARDM, I use DataGrip for our Mongo, SQL and Dynamo stuff. So it just felt like it makes sense to stay in one tool and I feel like datagrip must have this option and I must be missing it?

There's hope to have it in 2024.3
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-16877/Redis-Directories-for-keys-support-for-tree-structured-keys
